# Running PHP works in Command Prompt but not Git Bash

Tags: command-line, bash, php, environment-variables, git-bash

I've recently got a new laptop and have been in the process of setting it up.

I've installed WAMP, which is what I use to do my PHP development (installs Apache2, MySql, and PHP).

I also like to use Git Bash as my preferred command line tool, however when I try to do anything with PHP through the command line - I get a strange result; nothing happens and there is no error:

[image]

Now, if I run this through command prompt it works perfectly fine:

[image]

I've set the correct PATH variable for PHP and triple checked this:

[image]

What can I do to get PHP working through my Git Bash command line?

**EDIT**

Output of `ll /c/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/php`:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 james.b 1049089 122368 Aug 18  2016 /c/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/php*
```

Output of `echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n"`:

```
/c/Users/James.b/bin
/mingw64/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/mingw64/bin
/usr/bin
/c/Users/James.b/bin
/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath
/c/WINDOWS/system32
/c/WINDOWS
/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem
/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0
/c/Go/bin
/c/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10
/c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin
/c/Program Files/Microsoft/Web Platform Installer
/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/Client SDK/ODBC/110/Tools/Binn
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/120/Tools/Binn
/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/120/Tools/Binn
/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/120/DTS/Binn
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/120/Tools/Binn/ManagementStudio
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/120/DTS/Binn
/cmd
/c/Users/James.b/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps
/c/Users/James.b/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/bin
/c/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10
/usr/bin/vendor_perl
/usr/bin/core_perl
```

Comment: Type `which php` just to make sure, or launch php with the full path.

Comment: @simlev that returns `/c/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/php` which is the correct directory? Should the `php` at the end be `php.exe` as I am on windows?

Comment: It looks correct. Try with the full path `/c/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/php -v`, or go into that directory and type `./php -v`.

Comment: @simlev OK that worked. Is there something I can do to get it working? Otherwise I can just setup an alias for it

Comment: Yes, I suggest you simply alias it.

Comment: It works in my instance, I'd double check the path and the permissions. Please post the output of `echo $PATH` and `ll /c/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/php`.

Comment: @simlev have posted the outputs.

Comment: All seems ok to me (apart form the path being duplicated among another three or so but this shouldn't hurt). I can't find an explanation, I have the same "working" with PortableGit-2.14.0-64-bit and UniServer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What can I do to get PHP working through my Git Bash command line?

```
alias php='/c/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/php'
```

Comment: do we need to every time we open git bash? Or we can add it in some .profile file?

Comment: @Knight017 add it to `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 3):

I entered the following command in git bash and it worked.

```
alias php='/d/xampp/php/php.exe'
```

**Note: My xampp is installed in "D" drive (D:).**

Comment: How is your answer better/different than the other one?

Comment: There is a difference in the path. In my case, I needed to enter the full path including**php.exe**.

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot, we know you are using Windows. There is a solution as below:

1. Open `git bash`
2. Create `.bashrc` file in the home directory (~)

```bsh
cd ~
touch .bashrc
```

3. Add alias into the .bashrc file

```
alias php='winpty /c/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/php'
```

c/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/php => stands for `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\php` on Windows

Comment: How is this any different to the existing answers?

Comment: The alias definitions are held in memory, so there isn't really any strong performance argument for or against defining them in `.bashrc`. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/347198/190552

Answer (score 0):

My git bash was pointing to PHP in my XAMMP folder. Reinstalling XAMMP corrected the issue for me.

download XAMMP
https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html